# How to pass ACL properties to flutter amplify while uploading file to S3?

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, flutteramplify

Or How to upload an image to s3 with public access by Flutter Amplify?

In my current flutter project, I can't pass ACL:public-read property while uploading files to S3 using amplify.

And because of this, whenever I'm uploading a new file to s3, I need to make it public manually.
So I just want to upload a new file with public read access for everyone.

I found some solutions for the Javascript project but not in the Flutter project.

Below is a method, I'm using to upload.

```
Future<String> uploadFile(String fileName, File local) async {
try {
  Map<String, String> metadata = <String, String>{};
  metadata['name'] = 'filename';
  metadata['desc'] = 'A file';

  S3UploadFileOptions options = S3UploadFileOptions(accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.guest, metadata: metadata);
  UploadFileResult result = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(key: fileName, local: local, options: options);
  return result.key;
} catch (e) {
  print('UploadFile Err: ' + e.toString());
}

return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you find a solution to this?

Comment: @IgorCorradi Actually no,
But I did one change in my app that is wherever I was showing the image in my project by public URL, Now I'm getting that URL from Amplify. Amplify appends a token(with a default validity of 7 days) to that URL, So it can be shown by Image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far **Flutter Amplify** is not giving any option to upload images with public access.
It always uploads with private read access.

So I updated a few things in my project as described below.

Before Amplify integration I was uploading images to **S3** and storing that URL to **my server**, and wherever I have to display, I'm just fetching URL from my server and loading images.

But now I'm storing `key`(that is used to upload images to S3 by Amplify) to my server.

And to display the image I'm getting the image URL from Amplify using that `key`(which is stored in my server).
Amplify adds a token to the image URL with a default validity of 7 days

```
Future<String> getUrl(String key) async {
    try {
      S3GetUrlOptions options = S3GetUrlOptions(accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.guest, expires: 10000);
      GetUrlResult result = await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: key, options: options);
      String url = result.url;
      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      print('GetUrl Err: ' + e.toString());
    }

    return null;
  }
```

So it can be displayed by ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2) for declaring the client object that will be used for posting the request
You can find an example code in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952126/flutter-amazon-s3-image-upload)

Comment: but in the example multipart is used with `dio` to upload the file, my requirement is to use Amplify.Storage to upload files.